# Comparing 4 column values to make a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I'd like to hold the non NA values in a row, then pick the first element in 
the list as the final value for a new column (ncol).

Here's an example of what I'm trying to get and the code I've unable to get
to run...

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4) 
A <- c("A", "NA", "C", "R")
B <- c("G", "V", "NA", "T")
C <- c("NA", "NA", "NA", "Y")
D <- c("U", "W", "NA", "NA")


mydf <- data.frame(ID, A, B, C, D, ncol)


 ID  A  B  C  D ncol
1  1  A  G NA  U    A
2  2 NA  V NA  W    V
3  3  C NA NA NA    C
4  4  R  T  Y NA    R


mycol <- c(mydf$A, mydf$B, mydf$C, mydf$D)
for (i in seq(1:nrow(mydf))){
   listcolincldata <- lapply(mycol[i],[!is.na(mycols[i])])
   print(listcolincldata)
   mydf$newcol[i] <- (as.character(listcolincldata[1]))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Kris,
Below are two example solutions. One modifies your data frame to replace text "NA"s with true `NA` values and the second uses text recognition of "NA". Both make use of apply() used across the data frame's rows (by setting the margin argument to 1).

```
A <- c("A", "NA", "C", "R")
B <- c("G", "V", "NA", "T")
C <- c("NA", "NA", "NA", "Y")
D <- c("U", "W", "NA", "NA")

# First solution: convert text NA to true NA
eg1 <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
eg1[eg1 == "NA"] <- NA
eg1$solution <- apply(eg1, 1, function(rw) rw[!is.na(rw)][1])
eg1

# Second solution: string recognition
eg2 <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
eg2$solution <- apply(eg2, 1, function(rw) rw[rw != "NA"][1])
eg2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `apply` for this in order to loop row wise:

Data

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4) 
A <- c("A", NA, "C", "R")
B <- c("G", "V", NA, "T")
C <- c(NA, NA, NA, "Y")
D <- c("U", "W", NA, NA)

mydf <- data.frame(ID, A, B, C, D)
```

Solution:

```
#using apply is the same as lapply, but applied row wise
#na.omit will remove the NAs for each row
#then I use [2] to pick the first value after the ID column
#result is as shown in your output
mydf$ncol <- apply(mydf, 1, function(x) na.omit(x)[2])
```

Output:

```
> mydf
  ID    A    B    C    D ncol
1  1    A    G <NA>    U    A
2  2 <NA>    V <NA>    W    V
3  3    C <NA> <NA> <NA>    C
4  4    R    T    Y <NA>    R
```

Comment: na.omit() is more parsimonious than my `rw[!is.na(rw)][1]`! I am concerned the original example has text "NA" in place of true `NA`, though.

Comment: @ElizabethAB Hi Elisabeth. Thanks for the comment. Indeed the OP uses a text 'NA' but judging from his code (he uses `is.na`) his original data.frame probably has real R NAs. This is why I used `na.omit`. Otherwise, he should use your second solution.

Comment: Thanks! The NA's are from an uneven merge and as.character NA's I entered in a previous loop ...that may be the problem.... I'll change my loop & try again

Comment: Ok. I have all real NA's now & both ElizabethAB & LyzandeR examples fail saying .error. Dim(x) must have a positive length

Comment: I think it's the four parameters I'm passing in... I bring the mycols<- c(mydf$A, mydf$B, mydf$C, mydf$D into the loop hoping to iterate through. But I get the same dim() error plus an error saying "# of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: mycol <- list(mydf$A[i], mydf$B[i], mydf$C[i], mydf$D[i]) gets me the list of four values including NA .. It's still not iterating through saying

Comment: The point of the answers is to not use your loop but use the `apply` function as shown above. The `apply` function is a loop anyway. If you still try to use a loop you need to show us how you use it and it fails by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `max.col` with `ties.method='first'`.  This gets the column index of the first non-NA value, `cbind` it with the row index and get the value.

```
mydf$ncol <- mydf[cbind(1:nrow(mydf),max.col(!is.na(mydf[,-1]), 'first')+1L)]
mydf
#   ID    A    B    C    D ncol
#1  1    A    G <NA>    U    A
#2  2 <NA>    V <NA>    W    V
#3  3    C <NA> <NA> <NA>    C
#4  4    R    T    Y <NA>    R
```

#### data

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4) 
A <- c("A", NA, "C", "R")
B <- c("G", "V", NA, "T")
C <- c(NA, NA, NA, "Y")
D <- c("U", "W", NA, NA)

mydf <- data.frame(ID, A, B, C, D)
```

**NOTE:**  I created `NA` as a real NA instead of a character string. .